# Is it possible to turn off automatic flushing within the page cache in Linux?

Tags: file-io, page-caching

I am trying to write a C library, and, in short, I need to maintain a cache between the application and underlying non-volatile memory. Linux already does this with a page cache. It would be useful for me to use this instead of creating my own cache. From what I understand, the OS periodically syncs the contents of the page cache to storage. Is it possible for me to turn off automatic syncing/flushing to disk within the page cache in Linux? Perhaps on a per-application basis?